How do I recover or edit the correct file in this example?
OS: Ubuntu
tree -a 
.
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── script.js
└── src
    └── Main.elm

To edit: Main.elm I type :vim ./src/Main.elm
From there I wish to edit script.js.
So I type :e ../script.js. But Vim opens up a fresh buffer!
If instead, I type: :e ../../script.js, Vim apparently finds a script.js file and tells me there are several swap files and ask me which one do I want to use to recover.
My guess is that Vim's map of its buffers has somehow got corrupted.
How can I fix this?

Could you tell us what is the result of the :pwd command when you edit the ./src/Main.elm file?

Could you tell us what is the result of the :set directory? command?

Do you use 'autochdir'? If not, you should be writing :e script.js instead.

(Better title suggestions welcome)

The :edit command is relative to the Vim working directory (or Vim window/split working directory more precisely).
You can know what is the Vim working directory by using the :pwd command.
e.g.: To change the Vim working directory to the directory containing the current file you could do:
:cd %:h

Remark: To edit the file relatively to the current file you could do:
:edit %:h/../script.js

You can change the Vim working directory by using the :cd command (or :lcd if you want to change it only for the current window/split or :tcd if you want to change it only for all the windows/splits of the current tab).
By default the Vim working directory is the directory from which you started Vim (the . in your case). For some unknown reason it seems that your Vim working directory is something else (a child of ./src?)
You can configure Vim to automatically set the working directory to the directory that contains the file that you are currently editing by having the following line in your vimrc file (more information with :help 'autochdir'):
set autochdir

If you have several swap files corresponding to script.js it is usually because of on the two reasons:

You have multiple instances of running Vim (maybe running in the background after hitting Ctrl z) editing the same script.js file.
You had one instance of Vim editing script.js that has been killed (or that crashed) and because of that didn't had the opportunity to delete/clean the corresponding swap file.


A brilliantly comprehensive answer. Thank you @vivian-de-smedt. I made the novice error of thinking relative to the directory of the file I was editing and not the directory I was running vim from.

Welcome to Vim! Thanks for your feedback :-)
